# Problem when trying to install fpdb on ubuntu machine

Tags: python

I've been trying to get `fpdb` working on my Ubuntu desktop, but every time I try to install it from the Gz file, my system won't let me use `./configure` (saying file not found), and when I try to install it from the DEB file, I get

```
spencer@spencer-System-Product-Name:~$ fpdb
Python 2.7...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fpdb", line 85, in <module>
    import DetectInstalledSites
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/fpdb/DetectInstalledSites.py", line 47, in <module>
    Config=Configuration.Config()
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/fpdb/Configuration.py", line 805, in __init__
    game = Game(node = game_node)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/fpdb/Configuration.py", line 397, in __init__
    self.rows    = int( node.getAttribute("rows") )
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I'm something of a novice, so do you know anything that could help me properly install `fpdb`?

Also, I cannot find an installation manual for `fpdb` anywhere for installation on Ubuntu.

Also, whenever I run the `run_fpdb.py` file, I get:

```
['matplotlib/gtk', 'File not found: pylab', 'File not found: BeautifulSoup', 'File not found: wnck']
```

Does anybody know if I'm lacking certain repositories or files, or if I need to adjust something to install `fpdb`?

Comment: Could you provide the link for `fpdb` source?

Comment: Same problem here on Ubuntu 18. All python packages installed. Using FPDB 40.5.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `BeautifulSoup` and `wnck`, I managed to solve this problem by installing these two packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python-beautifulsoup
sudo apt-get install python-wnck
```

I didn't get errors for `matplotlib/gtk` and `pylab`, but I guess that's because I had already installed the Python packages listed on [this](http://fpdb.wikidot.com/install:_main) wiki page before.